# jax-rs how can I implement a webhook listener in REST server?

Tags: java, jax-rs, minio

I'm working on a migration project in Java that migrates BLOB files from table to a minio storage server. It operates in such a manner that a client reads from source table and sends certain data as POST values to a REST server. Those values are then written to a new table and an uploadlink is returned, through which the BLOB(converted to file) gets uploaded to minio server. This is the POST handler from resource class

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public UploadLink postFile(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, Attachment attachment) throws Exception {
    Integer id = attachmentService.createNew(attachment);
    UriBuilder builder = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder();
    String uploadLinkForFile = minioFileServer.getUploadLinkForFile("test", attachment.getUuid(), attachment.getName());
    UploadLink uploadLink = new UploadLink();
    uploadLink.setUploadLink(uploadLinkForFile);
    uploadLink.setLocation(builder.path(Integer.toString(id)).build());
    return uploadLink;
}
```

When called by a client, this method returns the uploadlink and using a PUT on the uploadlink, the client then uploads this file to minio server. What I want to do now is to implement a webhook listener in the server that would listen to the events published by minio server on every successful upload. How can I achieve this? Do I need to create an API that would act as the endpoint on minio's configuration? I would really appreciate any kind of advice/help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Minio has webhook feature which can be used to send event notifications to an endpoint. HTTP POST is used to send those notifications. So, what I did to tackle this issue was - I created an API that would accept POST requests like this.

```
@POST
@Path("webhook")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response webhookListener(NotificationConfiguration nc) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(nc);        
    return Response.ok().entity(jsonString).build();
}
```

So, basically what this API does is, it receives webhook notification from Minio which is of `NotificationConfiguration` data type and I've simply converted it to `JSON` using Jackson and returned it as an entity. The `JSON` data contains the event information.